# Get hidden value from wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Can i get value Hidden column from DataGrid?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="10" Binding="{Binding id}"  Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

Using this code, i get exception.

```
Data.IdServ = ((TextBlock)DataGridService.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row)).Text;


if (dgUserEnroll.SelectedItem != null)
{
  var data = (User)dgUserEnroll.SelectedItem;
  var userID = data.UserId;
 }
```

this is a not option, because i have tableadapter when receiveng data

Comment: What exceptio do you get?

Comment: Exception:  System.NullReferenceException Just replace YourClass with the Type of object you bound to the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your code behind too. You just need to hide the column in a different way:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="" MaxWidth="0" Binding="{Binding id}" />
```

i.e. remove the `Visibility` attribute and set `MaxWidth` to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Binding with id field, so use it instead of accessing cell content.

Comment: tell me how to do it?

Comment: You have binded your DataGrid to an ItemSource, the element of your ItemSource have an id field, so you can read the id field of your object.

Answer (score 1):

I found two ways

first

```
string ID = ((DataRowView)DataGridService.SelectedItem).Row["id"].ToString();
```

second

```
var data = (DataRowView)DataGridService.SelectedItem;
            var userId = data.Row["id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert selected item of  data grid view to `ItemsSource` of data grid view:

```
dataGridUser.ItemsSource is View_Users ==>
    dataGridUser.ItemsSource = database.Database.SqlQuery<View_Users>(
    "select * from view_users where 1=1"+searchString()).ToList();
```

Then, to get value `Hidden` or `Visible` column from `DataGrid`:

```
var id= ((View_Users)dataGridUser.SelectedItem).UserID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came with a simpler solution, suppose you have bound a List to the Datagrid, YourClass has Id property the XAML would look like :

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="ListeUrls" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="1,0,-1,27" >
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridCell_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vendor" Binding="{Binding Vendor}" Foreground="red" FontWeight="Bold" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Url" Binding="{Binding url}" ></DataGridTextColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

In the code behind :

Somewhere you have bound the ListeUrls:
    ListeUrls.ItemsSource = new List{ ....  };

```
        private void DataGridCell_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
           {
        var dataGridCellTarget = (DataGridCell)sender;
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dataGridCellTarget);
       .....
       }
```

You use the VisualTreeHelper to get the parent of the cell on which you triggered the mouse doubleclick. The parent has the properties of YourClass thus the Id.

I think no need to set the width of the hidden DataGridColumn, set its Visibility to Hidden is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    </DataTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>


            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="delete" Width="40"  Click="Delete_Click" Background="#FFD80000">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Delete"  Width="25" Margin="-10,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"></materialDesign:PackIcon>
                        </Button>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>


            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="edit" Width="40"  Click="Edit_Click" Background="#FF673AB7">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Edit"  Width="25" Margin="-10,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"></materialDesign:PackIcon>
                        </Button>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>


            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Width="300" Binding="{Binding [2]}" Header="Price"></DataGridTextColumn>-->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Just Set MaxWidth="0" you got value from column which you want to hide